# Play Audio when suspending to background

Tags: ios, audio

I have an app that under certain circumstances needs to play audio the moment it is pushed into background.

I can't use any background key, as I don't fulfill any requirements for these and Apple rejected my app, when I tried to use the background audio key.

Currently I'm start playing the audio file and then request extra processing time within `applicationDidEnterBackground:` The audio never gets played even though I have the processing time and the app is still running (I've used an NSTimer to check every 2 seconds).

As audio mode I'm using `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` with `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`.

With active background audio mode this works fine.

I also know, that I could use local notification and play the audio file there (as it is under 30 seconds), but that would be my last resort.

Does Apple prevent audio from being played in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` ?
I get a callback for `audioPlayerBeginInterruption:` immediately.

I've seen:

[Why does the following code to play audio in the background not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872305/why-does-the-following-code-to-play-audio-in-the-background-not-work)

But this doesn't seem to work anymore on iOS8.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your app should not be playing a sound (and certainly not a sound of any length) just because the user backgrounds it, and now Apple has succeeded in stopping you from doing this. You should accept this, abandon your attempts to work around this perfectly reasonable restriction, and move on.